# How to get the json files data in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I parsed 3 different json files to an html page using AngularJS.
 Here's my code:

Factory code

```
app.factory('myapp', ['$http', function($http) {        
function getLists() {
    var tab = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
    var list = [];
    for(i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        $http.get(tab[i]) 
        .then(function(res) {
            list.push(res.data);
        });
    }
    return list;
}

return {
    getLists: getLists
};
]);
```

What I want is to display the data of the different files by gender (male/female) That depends on the name 'nm'. The names of girls then the names of boys .The data of the first url in the first line , the second one in the second line , etc...

Html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list">
  <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
  <td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
  <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
  <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

I thinked about doing an if test in the controller where I specify the names of girls and the name of boys but it's not really obvious to me how to do that
what should I do?

Comment: You should use orderBy on the ng-repeat

Comment: @Weedoze orderBy gives me an alphabetic order. I have 3 names Bill, Sarah , Suzy I want this order 
Sarah
Suzy
Bill
The girls names then the boys names

Comment: Do you have a field to distinguish the gender?

Comment: give id for name and give orderby for id

Comment: You can have multiple order by like, `orderBy:'gender' | orderBy:'name'`

Comment: @tommoc I think I will use id thank you :)

Comment: @nournour , answer update in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give ID for the Name. Then Give `orderBy` for the `id`' of the name.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list| orderBy:ID">

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular has orderBy directive and you can use it inside ng-repeat to sort your data.

Try like that;

Replace genderField and nameField with your propery names.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in list| orderBy:['genderField','nameField']">
  <td>{{d.nm}}</td>
  <td>{{d.cty}}</td>   
  <td>{{d.hse}}</td>
  <td>{{d.yrs}}</td> 
</tr>
```

[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Answer (score 0):

I have created an id as @tommoc suggested me in a comment and that worked :)

Comment: can you write explicitly how? what if he deletes his comment in the future?

Comment: In fact I have did in the factory an if test depending on the names I have if it's a boy's name Id=2 If it's a girl's one Id=2 then in the ng-repeat I have did orderBy ID :)